# Are mobile agents an appropriate implementation mechanism for Distributed system?

Tags: agent, agents-jade

Mobile agents are self Autonomous: i.e. Agent itself decides when and where to migrate next. Applying this definition to a distributed shared memory systems where client's requests are cpu-intensive tasks, can we prefer mobile agents that can select a node itself to migrate to that node and execute client request on it. Is this a good paradigm for java based distributed application where client's requests are cpu-bounded and we let the mobile agent to choose a proper node itself.? if not then what alternatives are their in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

For intensive computing, I recommand that you read about the [grid computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_computing).

Mobile Agent paradigm may be useful to move from a node to an other and execute locally intensive tasks. But you need to consider security issus when designing such system. You need also a quantitative/qualitative comparison between the mobile agent paradigm and the client/server paradigm in order to decide which one is better. It depends on the application, so no one can tell you which one is the best.